# Why is sed not substituting string in file?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file where I'm trying to substitute one string for another with the following command

```
sed -e "s|value=\"localhost\"|value=\"$defaultHost\"|g" "$serv_dir"/controller1/server.xml
```

When `sed` runs it prints to std.out fine but when I `cat` the file the contents have not changed

Comment: Are you looking for `sed -i` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `-i` option to `sed` in order for it to change files in place.

Comment: yep, i'm an idiot. New to bash scripting/sed dunno how I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your alternative to editing in place with `-i` is to use an intermediate temporary file. It is a convenient method that allows you to test for successful completion of `sed -i` (similar to backup creation with `sed -i[ext]` which creates `filename.ext` as backup) To use a temporary file:

```
sed -e expression filename > tmpfile && cp tmpfile filename && rm tmpfile
```

Of course you can omit the final `&& cp tmpfile filename && rm tmpfile` and preserve the original `filename` until you confirm desired changes in `tmpfile.`